# Can i Directly add effects to pictures in vb6?

Tags: vb6, photo

I know that one can add filters to the pictures by adding partially transparent images as overlays upon them.But my question is whether an effect can be added directly to the picture.If it could be done,it would've been easier to create something like image editing softwares.
Thumbs up for the best Answers....

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what effects you have in mind? And what have you tried so far? Is it required for VB6 to be used?

Comment: You can use WIA 2.0 very easily to composite a translucent PNG on top of another image.  With more effort you can use the GDI+ Flat API to do it more directly.  Or you can use some 3rd party library.  Is there a specific question here someplace?  I don't see one.